# Speed up keras load model

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, load, keras, aws-lambda

I am generating some NN using `keras`. After the network is trained, I simply save it as:

```
model.save('model.h5')
```

Then, I load it as:

```
from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model("model.h5")
```

Everything works fine, however the loading takes up to 15 seconds. Given that I am trying to load and use the model on a `lambda` function with `AWS` where there is a 30 seconds time out, this is an issue. Is there anyway of speeding up the loading process?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this as I currently experiencing the same problem? Thanks